# Rails 4.2 error require 'open_uri'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) with `open_uri` to crawl web data in a Rails app. I have a `NokogiriCrawler` class:

```
class NokogiriCrawler
  require 'open_uri'

  def initialize
  end
end
```

but always have this error: `cannot load such file -- open_uri`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
require 'open-uri'
```

P.S. This is unrelated to your actual problem, but `require`s should almost always go at the top of your file, not inside your class declaration.